# Can't find Android Studio when creating plugin on Intellij using alternativeIdePath

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, plugins

What I need:

**Instead of opening a new instance of IntelliJ, I need it to open an Android Studio instance, since it will be an Android Studio plugin.**

What I've already achieved:

1. Create the simplest plugin to IntelliJ.
2. Execute this plugin and a new instance of IntelliJ opens.
3. Execute the plugin and it works just fine.

I have already changed the `alternativeIdePath` as many tutorials tell me to.

[Guide](https://proandroiddev.com/write-an-android-studio-plugin-part-1-creating-a-basic-plugin-af956c4f8b50) I've been following.

I have tried in many ways to set the `alternativeIdePath`.

```
intellij {
//    version '2018.2.5'
    alternativeIdePath "/opt/android-studio/bin/studio.sh"
}
```

also

```
intellij {
//    version '2018.2.5'
    alternativeIdePath "/opt/android-studio/bin/ ./studio.sh"
}
```

and some other naive ways...

I have also tried to runIde from my gradle in the right side.

[image: runIde]

Before I had my Android Studio and  `Android/Sdk` on my user location and it didn't work as well. So I moved everything to my `/opt/android-sdk` and `/opt/android-studio/` to see if it was the problem and it isn't.

Here is my log, since it doesn't find the Android Studio path:

```
09:04:43: Executing task ':runIde'...


> Configure project :
Cannot find alternate SDK path: /Applications/Android App /opt/android-studio/bin/studio.sh. Default IDEA will be used : /home/yurisnm/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.jetbrains.intellij.idea/ideaIC/LATEST-EAP-SNAPSHOT/2c16b45a5e389f84167a176491768cfd5a70e8a9/ideaIC-LATEST-EAP-SNAPSHOT
Cannot find alternate SDK path: /Applications/Android App /opt/android-studio/bin/studio.sh. Default IDEA will be used : /home/yurisnm/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.jetbrains.intellij.idea/ideaIC/LATEST-EAP-SNAPSHOT/2c16b45a5e389f84167a176491768cfd5a70e8a9/ideaIC-LATEST-EAP-SNAPSHOT

> Task :compileKotlin UP-TO-DATE
> Task :compileJava UP-TO-DATE
> Task :patchPluginXml UP-TO-DATE
> Task :processResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :classes UP-TO-DATE
> Task :instrumentCode UP-TO-DATE
> Task :postInstrumentCode
> Task :inspectClassesForKotlinIC UP-TO-DATE
> Task :jar UP-TO-DATE
> Task :prepareSandbox UP-TO-DATE

> Task :runIde
Cannot find alternate SDK path: /Applications/Android App /opt/android-studio/bin/studio.sh. Default IDEA will be used : /home/yurisnm/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.jetbrains.intellij.idea/ideaIC/LATEST-EAP-SNAPSHOT/2c16b45a5e389f84167a176491768cfd5a70e8a9/ideaIC-LATEST-EAP-SNAPSHOT
Cannot find alternate SDK path: /Applications/Android App /opt/android-studio/bin/studio.sh. Default IDEA will be used : /home/yurisnm/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.jetbrains.intellij.idea/ideaIC/LATEST-EAP-SNAPSHOT/2c16b45a5e389f84167a176491768cfd5a70e8a9/ideaIC-LATEST-EAP-SNAPSHOT
Cannot find alternate SDK path: /Applications/Android App /opt/android-studio/bin/studio.sh. Default IDEA will be used : /home/yurisnm/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.jetbrains.intellij.idea/ideaIC/LATEST-EAP-SNAPSHOT/2c16b45a5e389f84167a176491768cfd5a70e8a9/ideaIC-LATEST-EAP-SNAPSHOT
Cannot find alternate SDK path: /Applications/Android App /opt/android-studio/bin/studio.sh. Default IDEA will be used : /home/yurisnm/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.jetbrains.intellij.idea/ideaIC/LATEST-EAP-SNAPSHOT/2c16b45a5e389f84167a176491768cfd5a70e8a9/ideaIC-LATEST-EAP-SNAPSHOT
Cannot find alternate SDK path: /Applications/Android App /opt/android-studio/bin/studio.sh. Default IDEA will be used : /home/yurisnm/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.jetbrains.intellij.idea/ideaIC/LATEST-EAP-SNAPSHOT/2c16b45a5e389f84167a176491768cfd5a70e8a9/ideaIC-LATEST-EAP-SNAPSHOT
Cannot find alternate SDK path: /Applications/Android App /opt/android-studio/bin/studio.sh. Default IDEA will be used : /home/yurisnm/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.jetbrains.intellij.idea/ideaIC/LATEST-EAP-SNAPSHOT/2c16b45a5e389f84167a176491768cfd5a70e8a9/ideaIC-LATEST-EAP-SNAPSHOT
Cannot find alternate SDK path: /Applications/Android App /opt/android-studio/bin/studio.sh. Default IDEA will be used : /home/yurisnm/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.jetbrains.intellij.idea/ideaIC/LATEST-EAP-SNAPSHOT/2c16b45a5e389f84167a176491768cfd5a70e8a9/ideaIC-LATEST-EAP-SNAPSHOT
Cannot find alternate SDK path: /Applications/Android App /opt/android-studio/bin/studio.sh. Default IDEA will be used : /home/yurisnm/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.jetbrains.intellij.idea/ideaIC/LATEST-EAP-SNAPSHOT/2c16b45a5e389f84167a176491768cfd5a70e8a9/ideaIC-LATEST-EAP-SNAPSHOT
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=250m; support was removed in 8.0

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 14s
10 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 8 up-to-date
09:04:57: Task execution finished ':runIde'.
```

And now I got my back against the wall.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to remove the alternativeIdePath "studio.sh" of the path, like bellow:

```
intellij {
//    version '2018.2.5'
    alternativeIdePath "/opt/android-studio/"
}
```

Comment: There is also an example for `alternativeIdePath` in the plugin's documentation: https://github.com/JetBrains/gradle-intellij-plugin/blob/master/README.md#setup-dsl

Answer (score 0):

Same issue with PyCharm plugin development. Things gets worse when using JetBrains Toolbox (there is scary path to PyCharm IDE dir, check it out):

Setting build.gradle -> intellij -> `alternativeIdePath '/home/bla/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/PyCharm-P/ch-0/191.7479.30'` helps me and allows to test/debug my plugin via gradle runIde command.